# Computing Variances by Conditioning

Tags: self-study, variance, conditioning

I have trouble with the first part of this problem (Please take a look at the image below). This is an example problem from my old textbook years ago and I have had trouble understanding:

1. How Y is useful in solving the total variance?
2. Why E[X|Y] is a random variable, and how its values are obtained.
3. Why in calculating var(E[X|Y]), mean of E[X|Y] is used, instead of var(E[X|Y)) = E[(square of X)|Y] - (square of (E[X|Y]))?

[image]

Comment: $E(X\mid Y)=g(Y)$ (say) is a random variable whose distribution is given. Then they calculate its variance $V(E(X\mid Y))=V(g(Y))=E[g(Y)-E(g(Y))]^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is from [Bertsekas](http://www.mit.edu/~dimitrib/probbook.html) by the way; and to be precise since the limits are not shown in the image:
$$f_X(x)=\begin{cases}1/2, & 0\leq x < 1 \\ 1/4, & 1\leq x < 3 \\ 0, & \text{o/w}\end{cases}$$

First of all if you're OK with the statement in the solution that $E[X|Y]$ takes values $2$ and $1/2$ with probability $1/2$, then you're left with a new random variable, $Z=E[X|Y]$, where you're asked the variance of it, $\operatorname{var}(Z)$, in which you can execute the standard way of calculating the variance, as also pointed out by @StubbornAtom in the comments.

Let's derive $E[X|Y]$. First of all, it is a function of $Y$, and there are two cases at most because we have only two $Y$ values. So, we'll calculate $E[X|Y=1]$ and $E[X|Y=2]$. We can analytically find $f_{X|Y=1}(x)$ and find the expectation, but a simpler approach would be using the given plot. If $Y$ is $1$, then $X$ is uniform in $[0,1]$, which gives $E[X|Y=1]=1/2$. If $Y=2$, $X$ is uniform in $[1,3]$, which gives $E[X|Y=2]=2$.

**Edit**: After you added your bullet points:

1) PDF of $X$ is not in any standard form, e.g. uniform, exponential, normal etc. But, when we condition on $Y$, it's partitioned into two simpler (i.e. uniform PDFs) pieces: $f_{X|Y=1}(x)$ and $f_{X|Y=2}(x)$. We can directly use uniform PDF's pre-calculated statistics. You first need to understand that these two PDFs are uniform as a checkpoint.

2) $E[X|Y]$ is a random variable because it depends on $Y$. It doesn't depend on $X$, because $x$ is integrated out: $$E[X|Y]=\int_{\mathcal{X}} xf_{X|Y}(x)dx$$
Similarly, $E[X]$ is constant, $E[X|Y,Z,T]$ depends on $Y,Z,T$ etc.

3) Typical definition of variance is $\operatorname{var}(Z)=E[(Z-E[Z])^2]$; and here $Z=E[X|Y]$. Also, in your definition, you're confusing $\operatorname{var}(E[X|Y])$ with $\operatorname{var}(X|Y)$:
$$\operatorname{var}(E[X|Y])\neq E[X^2|Y]-E[X|Y]^2 = \operatorname{var}(X|Y)$$

Comment: I kind of understand why E[X|Y=1]=1/2. That is the value of fx(X) in [0,1], but please explain this part in more detail: "If =2,  is uniform in [1,3], which gives [|=2]=2.". This is one of the place I get stuck. How do you get that '2' while fx(x) is 1/4?

Comment: $E[X|Y=1]$ is not the value of $f(x)$ in $[0,1]$. It's actually $(0+1)/2=1/2$, because $X$ is uniform in the interval $[0,1]$. Similarly, when $Y=2$, $X$ is uniform in $[1,3]$, which means an expectation of $(1+3)/2=2$.

Comment: Thank you for your points 1 and 2, and now I understand better.

Comment: Ok, I also understand that I have been confused between the definitions of var(E[X|Y]) and var(X|Y）。Then, my remaining question is why var(Z) was obtained using the mean of E[X|Y] (or mean of Z) instead the definition you pointed out? Where is that formula author used coming from? It is obviously different

Comment: It's using the standard formula of variance, which I also quoted: $\operatorname{var}(Z)=E[(Z-E[Z])^2]$. This means we subtract the mean from each value, square and average them.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying further. So, the value of E[Z] is the sum of[ (probability of each interval) X ( the value of Z in each interval)] . Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, because `probability of each interval` is the `probability of Z in that interval`, e.g. $P(X\in [0,1])=P(Z=1/2)$. For another view, $E[Z]=E[E[X|Y]]=E[X]=5/4$, from the law of iterated expectations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying the details! I got everything now.

Comment: In general, $E[X^2|Y]$ is the expected value of $X^2$ when we know $Y$. And, $var(X|Y)$ is the variance of $X$ when we know $Y$.

Comment: I am first time asking question. Please explain how to accept/upvote the answer. Thanks. (I logged in using Facebook login but I got a message saying I cannot vote for my own question...)

Comment: Click on the tick below the answer to accept it. But, I think you won’t be able to upvote it till you’re 15 rep.